# Green function of the 2-dimensional "curl" operator

Tags: calculus, greens-function

I want to find the solution to the equation:
$$
x \partial_y f - y \partial_x f = \delta^{(2)}(x,y) \,,
$$
where $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar function, and $\delta^{(2)}(x,y)$ is the 2-dimensional Dirac Delta function centered at the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I know that the solution of the homogeneous equation $\partial_y f - y \partial_x f = 0$ is:
$$
G(x,y) = h(x^2 + y^2) \,,
$$
for any single-argument function $h$.So shouldn't $G(x,y)$ for a certain $h$ be the solution to the equation above, like what happens for the Green function of the Laplacian in 3D?

However, I'm not sure how to prove that. I can require $f$ to be a solution of the first equation in a weak sense:
$$
\int_B dx dy \, g(x,y) \left( x \partial_y f - y \partial_x f \right) = g(0,0) \,,
$$
where the integral is over a compact region $B$ that includes the origin. I can then write the left-hand side as:
$$
\int_B dx dy \, g(x,y) \epsilon^{ij} x_i \partial_j f  \,,
$$
where $\epsilon^{12}=-\epsilon^{21}=1$ and $\epsilon^{11}=\epsilon^{22}=0$, and I can integrate by part the derivative:
$$
\int_B dx dy \, g(x,y) \epsilon^{ij} x_i \partial_j f  = \int_B dx dy \partial_j \left(g(x,y) \epsilon^{ij} x_i \, f \right) -   \int_B dx dy \, f  \epsilon^{ij} x_i \partial_j g(x,y)
$$
$$
= \oint_{\partial B} d\sigma_j \epsilon^{ij} x_i \, f \, g(x,y)  -   \int_B dx dy \, f  \epsilon^{ij} x_i \partial_j g(x,y)
$$
where $d\sigma_j$ is the normal to the boundary curve $\partial B$.

This is where I stop... taking $g(x,y) = 1$ I can prove that the first of the two integral is zero when $f(x,y) = G(x,y)$, but then of course the second integral is zero too. Is it possible to show that the above expression is equal to $g(0,0)$, or perhaps it's just not true that $G(x,y)$ weakly solves the first equation?

Comment: For the record, the solution to the homogeneous equation is $c(x^2+y^2)$ for any single-variable function $c$.

Comment: Duh you're right, thanks! I'll change the text so the readers don't get distracted by that.

Comment: Because this operator is first-order, the Green's function will have a step function in it somewhere. Maybe that's what's tripping you up?

Answer (score 2):

1. The 2D curl operator is $\partial_{\theta}$ in [polar coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarCoordinates.html), so since the 2D [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\delta^2(x,y)$ does not depend on [$\theta={\rm atan2}(x,y)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), the Greens function is morally $G(x,y)=\theta\delta^2(x,y)$, which is not mathematically well-defined.
2. A better strategy is to not use a Greens function and instead to Fourier expand a general inhomogeneous source term in a Fourier series
   $$ \partial_{\theta}f(r,\theta)~=~\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_n(r)e^{in\theta},$$
   which has a formal (possibly multivalued) solution
   $$ f(r,\theta)~=~\theta c_0(r)~+~\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}}\frac{c_n(r)}{in}e^{in\theta} ~+~h(r). $$